# Why progress changed is not called?

Tags: android, android-view, android-seekbar

I'm extending SeekBar:

```
public class NutritionalSeekBar extends SeekBar implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    public NutritionalSeekBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NutritionalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public NutritionalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public NutritionalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        progress = (Math.round(progress / 50)) * 50;
        seekBar.setProgress(progress);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
}
```

Then use it in xml:

```
<com.package.views.NutritionalSeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seek_bar_carbos"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:progress="50" />
```

Why the callback progress changed is never called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a `NutritionalSeekBar` instance to be its own `OnSeekBarChangeListener`, you have to set it as such. You should also chain your constructors. For example:

```
public class NutritionalSeekBar extends SeekBar implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    public NutritionalSeekBar(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public NutritionalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public NutritionalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    }
    ...

}
```

Comment: Ok, I understood the constructors chain. What about chaining only if I'm on Lollipop for the last constructor?

Comment: Doing it this way lets you keep your initialization code to a minimum. Calling `this(context, null);` in the first constructor is calling the second constructor, which in turn calls the third. Since the first constructor doesn't have an `AttributeSet` parameter, we just pass the default value to the second constructor. Same for calling the third constructor from the second.

Comment: Oh, I just realized you're implementing the four-parameter constructor as well. In that case, you'll need to call your initialization code there, too, since that constructor is only available in Lollipop or above. If you plan to add more initializations than just the listener, you can move them to a separate method, and call that method from both the three- and four-parameter constructors. Otherwise, you can just call `setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);` again in the four-param.